# Nexus 4 Ubuntu Dual Boot?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Not sure if this is already answered.  I remember that the Ubuntu Edge claimed it could dual boot to normal android and ubuntu.  Is this still the case?  If i install on my Nexus 4 will i have a choice to boot into either Ubuntu or my already existing Android OS?

Comment: My first Google result on this was [Multi ROM for Nexus 4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2403992) on XDA developers. It seems very much hardware-specific (unlike dual booting on a PC) and not yet capable of booting Ubuntu, but it's something to keep an eye on.

Comment: The Ubuntu Edge could do this. Not necessarily any phone running Ubuntu Touch. I think you are confusing Ubuntu Edge and Ubuntu Touch.

Answer (score 2):

How to Dual boot/Multi boot Ubuntu Touch/Ubuntu Phone on Nexus 4.

Yes, it is very much hardware specific because all the different phones on the market use very different System-On-Chip(SOC)'s in them.  The Nexus 4 is definitely the best one for running Ubuntu Phone/Ubuntu Touch on at present because it has the most RAM: 2GB and it has the most cores(QUAD-CORE) and most importantly because the Nexus 4 is one of only four devices officially supported by Canonical.

I have done my best to summarize everything necessary to dual-boot android 4.2.2 and the latest functional/stable(saucy 100) ubuntu phone on the Google Nexus 4:

http://adequatech.ca/#ubuntuphonerunsonwindrogersnexus4

It takes about 30 minutes to an hour to finish the entire recipe and get up and dual-booting.

The real question here:  "Is all this worth the effort?".  Yes. You will have a phone with a different GUI, a conversation piece, that works for daily tasks.  It is easier to develop applications for and most importantly it is because it's a real GNU/Linux running on the phone just like your desktop which is most important for your digital freedom and digital privacy.  The Google Nexus 4 is definitely worth buying.  Google should continue selling this phone.

The reason Android 4.2.2 is specified is because some of the radio firmware changed in later versions of Android jellybean and Android kitkat resulting in losing call/sms/wifi capability from within Ubuntu Touch/Phone. Don't upgrade the Android version on the Nexus 4 after the above recipe.  In your Android 4.2.2, disable automatic upgrades as much as you can in play store settings and security settings.